# ImportError: Failed to import ‘com.aspose’ after building exe in python 3.11.1

Tags: python, aspose-cells, jpype, python-3.11

I use Python’s AsposeCells to generate PNG images from excel files. First off, it works properly with my Python code. But I encountered this issue when I tried to turn my script into an exe file with Pyinstaller. I couldn’t come up with a solution for this. Please assist me.The line that generates the exception and the exception are given below.

[image: exception]
[image: code]

`My dependencies: Python = 3.11.1 aspose-cells=23.1.0 JPype1=1.4.1`

Comment: Please include any relevant information [as text directly into your question](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), do not embed images of source code or errors. Images make it difficult to efficiently assist you as they cannot be copied and offer poor usability to others as they cannot be searched. See: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/).

Answer (score 0):

Could you please refer to the following steps if it works:

Create a folder as c:\app, and copy example.py(attached) to c:\app
Now, open your command prompt, type the below commands in the prompt.

1. cd c:\app
2. pyinstaller example.py
3. copy the jars(aspose-cells-23.1.jar, bcprov-jdk15on-160.jar, bcpkix-jdk15on-1.60.jar, JavaClassBridge.jar. They exist in C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\asposecells\lib folder) to c:\app
4. edit example.spec to add datas section like below

```
mydatas = [(’./aspose-cells-22.11.jar’, ‘.’),
('./bcprov-jdk15on-160.jar', '.'),
('./bcpkix-jdk15on-1.60.jar', '.'),
('./JavaClassBridge.jar', '.') ]
a = Analysis(

['example.py'],

pathex=[],

binaries=[],

datas=mydatas,

hiddenimports=[],

hookspath=[],

hooksconfig={},

runtime_hooks=[],

excludes=[],

win_no_prefer_redirects=False,

win_private_assemblies=False,

cipher=block_cipher,

noarchive=False,
)
```

5. pyinstaller example.spec
6. cd c:\app\dist\example
7. example.exe

PS. I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.